# Storing a large image in java - tutorial

Tags: java, jai

I need to save a large image on disk - so large it creates outofmemory errors (like 10000x10000 px). It's suppose to be a tiling and I have the tile stored in memory as a BufferedImage. I read something about TiledImage class being able to work only with part of image, the rest being stored on disk, but I haven't found a simple example of how to do this?
**Could you please point me to or create a tutorial for dummies on how to store a large image on disk without having it all in memory?** Like "create large image straight on disk like this:", "access its part and store data in it like this:" or however it works..

I know this has been asked here a couple of times, but I read through all of that and googled a lot but still haven't found a whole working (or comprehendable) example. Maybe it's the language barrier, or I'm just stupid in this kinda stuff, anyway, help, please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked out [DiskMemImage](http://code.google.com/p/jaitools/wiki/DiskMemImage), from their documentation:

> This class serves the same purpose as JAI's standard TiledImage class: namely, a writable image that can accommodate a variety of data types, an optional ColorModel, and data arranged in tiles. However, unlike TiledImage, ***DiskMemImage uses disk as well as memory storage*** to allow very large images to be handled in limited memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a look to [PNGJ](https://code.google.com/p/pngj/), I created that library for a similar scenario.

Answer (score -1):

I would just increase your maximum memory, it is much simpler. Try it with `-Xmx1g` on the command line.

There is no magic to using tiles. You just break up your image into smaller images when you stitch together on the screen so it looks like a large one. e.g. Google maps do this.

Answer (score -1):

Easy way to solve OutOfMemoryError in java is to increase the maximum heap size by using JVM options

Comment: salam ,well thats just avoiding the prob , not the solution

Comment: salam ,well thats just avoiding the prob , not the solution

Comment: if you're dealing with the real time production , deployed website on web , then this not gonna help you , plus heavy expense

Comment: ohk , there i am not here to disagree or make issues , just sharing my experience