# OutOfMemoryError: Jave heap space when jtable saved as Image

Tags: java, jtable, bufferedimage

Currently I am saving a jtable as jpeg using the below method, when the dimension of the jtable became 2590, 126181, java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space exception occurs at "BufferedImage constructor", when the size of the table is small the image gets saved successfully.

```
 public BufferedImage saveComponentAsJPEG(JTable table, String filename) {
   Dimension size = table.getSize();
   BufferedImage myImage = 
     new BufferedImage(size.width, size.height,
     BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
   Graphics2D g2 = myImage.createGraphics();
   table.paint(g2);  
   return myImage;    
 }
```

How to save a jtable with bigger size in pdf or jpeg image?

Comment: Add more memory with -Xmx=2048M as the parameter for java command.

Comment: I should not increase the Heap memory, I am looking for an idea of slicing the jtable into small size images and then save it in pdf image. is it possible?

Comment: Perhaps you should change your question title to reflect what you're trying to achieve. One thing that occurs to me, if you break the JTable into pieces, each piece may be laid out differently (different column sizes, for example).

Comment: Here's a way to [create `BufferedImage`s outside the heap](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/master/sandbox/sandbox-common/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/image/MappedImageFactory.java) (using nio `MappedByteBuffer`s). Another thing you could try, is to use the [Swing print API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/swing.html) and print to a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Info:

You asked how to "split the JTable into different small images":

As you go through my code below please read my comments, they help explain what is happening and will help you grasp a better understanding of how a JTable/JComponent can be painted to lots of small images. At the heart my code is similar to yours, but there are two key points:

1) Rather than create a single large BufferedImage, I create a single small image that is then used multiple times, therefore leaving a very small memory footprint.

2) With the single image, I use Graphics.translate() to paint a small part of the JTable each time.

The following code was tested with a large JComponents (2590 x 126181) and a tile size of 200x200, and the whole process did not exceed 60mb of memory:

```
//width = width of tile in pixels, for minimal memory usage try 200
//height = height of tile in pixels, for minimal memory usage try 200
//saveFileLocation = folder to save image tiles
//component = The JComponent to save as tiles
public static boolean saveComponentTiles(int width, int height, String saveFileLocation, JComponent component)
{   
    try
    {
        //Calculate tile sizes
        int componentWidth = component.getWidth();
        int componentHeight = component.getHeight();
        int horizontalTiles = (int) Math.ceil((double)componentWidth / width); //use (double) so Math.ceil works correctly.
        int verticalTiles = (int) Math.ceil((double)componentHeight / height); //use (double) so Math.ceil works correctly.
        System.out.println("Tiles Required (H, W): "+horizontalTiles+", verticalTiles: "+verticalTiles);

        //preset arguments
        BufferedImage image;

        //Loop through vertical and horizontal tiles
        //Draw part of the component to the image
        //Save image to file
        for (int h = 0; h < verticalTiles; h++)
        {
        for (int w = 0; w < horizontalTiles; w++)
        {
            //check tile size, if area to paint is smaller than image then shrink image
            int imageHeight = height;
            int imageWidth = width;
            if (h + 1 == verticalTiles)
            {
            imageHeight = componentHeight - (h * height);
            }
            if (w + 1 == horizontalTiles)
            {
            imageWidth = componentWidth - (w * width);
            }
            image = new BufferedImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics g = image.getGraphics();

            //translate image graphics so that only the correct part of the component is panted to the image
            g.translate(-(w * width), -(h * height));
            component.paint(g);

            //In my example I am saving the image to file, however you could throw your PDF processing code here
            //Files are named as "Image.[h].[w]"
            //Example: Image 8 down and 2 accross would save as "Image.8.2.png"
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(saveFileLocation + "Image." + h +"."+ w + ".png"));
            //tidy up
            g.dispose();
        }
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Just call it like so:

```
boolean result = saveComponentTiles(200, 200, saveFileLocation, jTable1);
```

Also if you haven't done it already, you should only call the method from a [different thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) because it will hang your application when dealing with large components.

---

If you have not picked a PDF library yet, then I highly recommend looking at [iText](http://itextpdf.com/).

---

Original Post:

> The process you are looking for is quite simple, however it may take some work.
>
> You were on the right track thinking about parts, but as David
>   mentioned you shouldn't mess with the jTable, instead you will need a
>   to make use of the `TiledImage` class, or do something yourself with
>   `RenderedImage` and `Rasters`.
>
> This sort of method basically uses HDD space instead of memory and
>   lets you create a large image in lots of smaller parts/tiles, then
>   when its done you can save it all to a single image file.
>
> ---
>
> This answer may also help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14069551/1270000

Comment: Going down a different line of though: Do you really need to save it as a PDF or image? Why not try saving the data as a spreadsheet/CSV file? It would fix your memory issue, and still have all the information in an easy to use format.

Comment: I am looking for a mechanism where I should be able to split the Jtable into different small images and then I will append these small images into a PDF file. Is there any way to split a table into different images?

Comment: @user3201343 See my updated answer, I believe this is what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: No, that is not a simple table, it is like a image which shows the statistics, I have used renderers to display the statistics. So after seeing the statistics when the user wants to save the viewed statistics, they should be able to save it, this is what my requirement is. I am getting problem when the user click the save button if the size of the table is too large.

Comment: @user3201343 Sorry I don't understand your point. You asked for a "mechanism to split the Jtable into different small images", that is exactly what my code does, just pass any JTable or JComponent to it. In my example I save each image(part of the JTable) to file as it is created, resulting in the whole JTable being saved to file in pieces. You need to alter that last section of code to instead append each image directly to a PDF instead of saving each image to file.

Comment: @user3201343 Just to make sure you understand: By making one very large image your code throws an `OutOfMemoryError`, and by making many small images you will also throw the same `OutOfMemoryError`. Inside my code I only create one small image at a time, and because there is only one small image it will use very little memory and will not give you the `OutOfMemoryError`. To solve the error you need to process each image as it is made (see my code), instead of your idea to create lots of small images and trying to hold them all in program memory because it will crash.

Comment: sorry for the ambiguity, consider my jtable like an image of size (2590 x 126181), now I want to save the jtable image in a pdf file. Currently I convert the jtable to BufferedImage and then port BufferedImage to PDF file. If the size of the jtable exceeds (2590 x 126181) outofmemoryerror occur. is there any possibility where i should slice the jtable, Eg: consider my jtable dimension is 100 x  10, so I should have 10 buffered images of size (10 x 10), each bufferedimage I will append in each page of the PDF file. I cant able to slice the

Comment: so I should have 10 buffered images of size (10 x 10) (i.e) i should slice jtable as (0-10, 10-20, 20-30, .... 90-100), each bufferedimage I will append in each page of the PDF file. I tried your code but "component.paint(g);" takes more time (approx 1 minute) for each iteration.

Comment: It is odd that each iteration takes so long, did you use my code exactly or alter it somehow? The only other things I can really suggest is 1) Try to approach your problem a different way, maybe save it in a different format? 2) Use the TiledImage class from JAI, it may help with performance: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/current-142188.html http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jaifaq-138288.html

Comment: @user3201343 See this Q&A it shows a basic example of using a TiledImage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982422/write-swing-component-to-large-tiff-image-using-jai